# Como usar aspas duplas numa aplicação python executando um subprocess

Tags: python, string

Estou tentando adicionar uma nova rede wifi via linha de comando em uma Raspberry Pi, porém quando eu passo a string contendo os dados da rede WiFi as aspas que devem ficar entre o nome do login e senha se perdem, gostaria de entender como poderia passar os dados sem perder as aspas. Abaixo vou disponibilizar parte dos códigos para um melhor entendimento do meu problema.

Código:

```py
cmd="echo \"network={ \n    ssid=\"" + ssdi_usr + "\""+"\n    psk=\"" + psk_usr + "\"\n    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n}\" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Output:

```
Insira nome da rede: jimi
Insira a senha: yay
echo "network={ 
    ssid="jimi"
    psk="yay"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Como fica no arquivo `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
network={ 
    ssid=jimi
    psk=yay
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Comment: Já tentei colocar: `\"\"\"` porém também não deu certo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sua string `cmd` contém isso:

```bsh
echo "network={ 
    ssid="jimi"
    psk="yay"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

E quando você roda esse comando, as aspas são ignoradas. Por exemplo, teste esse comando:

```
echo "abc"def"xyz"
```

A saída será `abcdefxyz`. Isso porque as aspas são interpretadas pelo *shell* antes de ser passadas ao `echo`. Tanto que `echo abc` e `echo "abc"` produzem o mesmo resultado ([leia aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24647) para mais informações).

Para que o `echo` imprima as aspas, você tem que escapá-las com `\` - ou seja, `echo \"abc\"` imprime `"abc"`, mas `echo "abc"` imprime apenas `abc`.

Só que em uma string do Python, o caractere `\` deve ser escrito como `\\`. E para ter as aspas na própria string, você teria que usar `\"` (ou trocar as aspas duplas por aspas simples). Então ficaria assim:

```
cmd = 'echo "network={ \n    ssid=\\"' + ssdi_usr + '\\"\n    psk=\\"' + psk_usr + '\\"\n    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n}" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
```

As aspas em volta de `network` eu mantive para que as quebras de linha sejam consideradas. Mas as aspas correspondentes ao `ssid` e `psk` tem que ser escapadas com `\`. Com isso, o comando gerado será:

```bsh
echo "network={ 
    ssid=\"jimi\"
    psk=\"yay\"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

E com isso, as aspas serão escritas no arquivo, que ficará assim:

```
network={
    ssid="jimi"
    psk="yay"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

---

Se estiver usando Python >= 3.6 pode trocar a concatenação por [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
cmd = f'echo \"network={{ \n    ssid=\\"{ssdi_usr}\\"\n    psk=\\"{psk_usr}\\"\n    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n}}" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
```

A diferença é que as variáveis `ssdi_usr` e `psk_usr` são colocadas entre colchetes, e seus valores são colocados diretamente na string. A parte "chata" é que os próprios colchetes tem que ser escritos como `{{` e `}}`.

---

Dito isso, em vez de invocar um comando do shell, não é mais fácil usar o próprio Python para escrever no arquivo?

```
with open('/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf', 'a') as arq:
    arq.write(f"""echo network={{
    ssid="{ssdi_usr}"
    psk="{psk_usr}"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}}""")
```

Assim você não fica dependendo das regras de escape "aninhadas" - pois no seu código você precisa se preocupar com as regras de como escrever o `\` e as aspas no Python, para que elas sigam as regras de escape do Bash, já usando somente o Python, é uma "camada" a menos para se preocupar.

Answer (score 1):

Estava com problemas por que as informações, tais nome da rede e senha eram entradas fornecidas pelo usuário, consegui achar um meio termo para a solução:

```
cmd="echo 'ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev\nupdate_confg=1\ncountry=BR\nnetwork={ \n    ssid=" + '"' + ssdi_usr + '"' + "\n    psk=" + '"' + psk_usr + '"' + "\n    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n}' > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"

subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para escapar as aspas duplas envolva todo o conteúdo com aspas simples. Por exemplo:

```
Insira nome da rede: jimi
Insira a senha: yay
echo 'network={ 
    ssid="jimi"
    psk="yay"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}'
```

Outro método seria usar `\` antes de cada aspa dupla que você queira escapar, por exemplo:

```
Insira nome da rede: jimi
Insira a senha: yay
echo "network={ 
    ssid=\"jimi\"
    psk=\"yay\"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}"
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso, porém também não deu certo, quando eu escrevo o conteúdo no arquivo usando esse comando `echo "conteudo" >> /etc/destino` as aspas se perdem